# Combine two select results into one column

Tags: mysql, select, union

Lets say this is the result of first select statement

```
topic
 a 
 b
 c
```

and this is the result of second select statement

```
user
 d
 e
```

How to combine this two colums into ONE column with a new column name? I am trying to use `UNION` however its not working

```
SELECT topic FROM topic_table WHERE topic LIKE '%' 
UNION
SELECT user FROM user_table WHERE topic LIKE '%'
```

and my desired column would be like

```
desired_column
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
```

Comment: anything common in both table

Comment: How is `union` not working?  What results do you want?

Comment: no nothing common with them

Comment: @GordonLinoff see my edit

Comment: @er.irfankhan11 both columns are same type with 'VARCHAR(50)'.  came to my mind just now

Answer (score 1):

name your topic columns equally:

```
SELECT topic as topic FROM a WHERE topic LIKE '%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT other_topic as topic FROM b WHERE other_topic LIKE '%';
```

Playground:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66ea3e/1

Answer (score 0):

Your desired results should come from this query:

```
SELECT topic as desired_column FROM topic_table WHERE topic LIKE '%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT user FROM user_table WHERE topic LIKE '%';
```

I changed the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` so the query does not remove duplicates (your question says nothing about that).

The `WHERE` clauses are rather non-sensical.  It is better to just use `WHERE topic IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: this query returns this  -> `desire d e`. Which means its the result set of my second statement with a different column name

Comment: why you did not put  `as desired_column` into second select?